# UnHandled Exception : Unable to capture the error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase Auth with Flutter. Below is my code.

**login_screen.dart**

```
RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    color: blackShadeColor,
                    child: Text("Login",
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 16))),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _loginScreenController
                          .login(
                              context: context,
                              email: _emailController.text,
                              password: _passwordController.text)
                          .catchError((error) {
                        print(error);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

**login_screen_controller.dart**

```
class LoginScreenController {

  /**
   * Login Function
   */
  Future<void> login({BuildContext context, String email, String password}) async {
    
      FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService = FirebaseAuthService();
      firebaseAuthService.signInWithEmail(email, password).then(((value){})).catchError((onError){
        throw onError;
      });
    
  }
}
```

**firebase_auth_service.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirebaseAuthService with ChangeNotifier {
  //Sign in with username and password
  Future<void> signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        print("Sign in success: " + user.email);
      } else {
        print("sign in failed");
        throw Exception(
            "Sign in Failed. Please check your email and password again");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw (e);
    } finally {
      //notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

If there is an error, like wrong password, wrong email or something, the firebase throws an error. The issue is my attempts to catch that error is not working as expected. Instead I end up with `Unhandled exception`. This is the error I get.

```
I/flutter (18418): [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
E/flutter (18418): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18418): #0      FirebaseAuthService.signInWithEmail[39;49m
 package:wnenterprises/services/firebase_auth_service.dart
E/flutter (18418): <asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18418): #1      LoginScreenController.login[39;49m
 package:wnenterprises/controllers/login_screen_controller.dart
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18418): #2      _LoadingScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
 package:wnenterprises/screens/login_screen.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18418): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)[39;49m
E/flutter (18418):
```

What is really happening here?

Comment: "The issue is my attempts to catch that error is not working as expected." How do you know?  You rethrow the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of async await, you can try the regular .then() method and use the catch error function. :

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((val){print(val);}).catchError((e){print("Exception: " + e.toString())});
```

Comment: I am seperating the UI from the business logic. I do not want to mix them with each other.